# ASP.NET MVC 2 - First submit button on site doesn't work - rest is fine!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, submit, form-submit

Sorry for unclear title - I don't know how to describe that problem in one sentence. Code sample will make it clear.

First UP button do nothing when clicked. Rest works like it should!

Below my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GeekClick.ViewModels.HomeViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Beta</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainPageLinks" runat="server">
    <h2>Najlepsze linki w sieci</h2>
    <div id="HomePageLinks">
        <%foreach (var link in Model.Links) { %>
            <a href="<%:link.LinkURL %>"><b><%:link.Description %></b></a><br />
            <%: Html.ActionLink("details", "Index", "Link", new {id = link.LinkID}, null) %>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("UpVote", "Home", new { linkId = link.LinkID }, FormMethod.Post)) {%>
                    <input type="submit" value="UP" /> <% } %> 
            <%: link.Votes %>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("DownVote", "Home", new { linkId = link.LinkID }, FormMethod.Post)) {%>
                    <input type="submit" value="DOWN" /> <% } %> 
        <% } %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult UpVote(int linkId)
{
    var updateLink = _geekDb.Link.Single(a => a.LinkID == linkId);
    updateLink.Votes++;
    _geekDb.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult DownVote(int linkId)
{
    var updateLink = _geekDb.Link.Single(a => a.LinkID == linkId);
    updateLink.Votes--;
    _geekDb.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And finally generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1">
    <title>Beta</title>
<title>
</title></head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="./" id="form1">

<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE1NDk5OTQxMTBkZLMRoMOmMkoaJsHIkFWLWjn7HFSzna1LBeMqvRiCxdDQ" />
</div>
    <div id ="mainPage" >
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div id="HomePageLinks">
            <a href="Some link"><b>Something                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </b></a><br />
            <a href="/Link/Index/1">details</a>
            <form action="/Home/UpVote?linkId=1" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="UP" /> </form>3
            <form action="/Home/DownVote?linkId=1" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="DOWN" /> </form> 
            <a href="somelink"><b>Somedesc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         </b></a><br />
            <a href="/Link/Index/2">details</a>
            <form action="/Home/UpVote?linkId=2" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="UP" /> </form>10
            <form action="/Home/DownVote?linkId=2" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="DOWN" /> </form> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There shouldn't be viewstate, should be?

I can't see there any problem in code. Someone can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like somewhere (perhaps in your Main.Master) you have a `<form runat="server" />` that's messing things up.

It makes sense why your first button does not work - notice `<form method="post" action="./">` at the top of your output - it's clashing with your other form and posting to the wrong action.

Comment: There was form in Main.Master. Thx!